# Logging python errors on raspberry pi

Tags: python, linux, pyqt, raspberry-pi

I'm having a helluva time debugging a python app I've written for an embedded raspberry pi project I'm working on because it's using a TFT screen instead of a full monitor and has no monitor/keyboard, so i'm having to launch the python app via an icon on the TFT desktop (very small).  I can't launch the app via SSH because it requires X (due to PyQT4), so to get it running on the RPi, it has to be launched using the desktop icon on the device itself.

The desktop icon launches a shell script that uses the following:

`sudo python appname.py >> logfile.log`

but that doesn't write whatever error it's hitting, it only logs whatever I'm doing prior to any error.

If I remove the SD card from the RPi and put it into a 2nd RPi I have connected to a full mouse/keyboard/display, I can run the python app and see the error in the terminal, but that doesn't help me figure out what's happening on the fully assembled device.

**How do I log the error that I would normally see in the terminal?**

EDIT: Of course I'm doing error catching in the app, but I'm sending shell commands in the python app that could be the problem that wouldn't be caught by a try/catch in python.  I'd like to catch ALL of the output in the terminal when you launch a python script regardless of it's source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands you're just capturing stdout.  Modify your invocation to the following:

```
sudo python appname.py >> logfile.log 2>&1
```

This will redirect both stdout and stderr.

Comment: when I add `2>&1`, the app wont launch at all and nothing is written

Comment: so it turns out it was because I had `Terminal=false` set in the icon I'm using to launch.  setting it to true made everything work

Answer (score 1):

For only error you can use:

```
sudo python appname.py 2>> logfile.log
```

For only `stdout`:

```
sudo python appname.py >> logfile.log
#same as sudo python appname.py 1>> logfile.log
```

For both `stdout` and `stderr`:

```
sudo python appname.py >> logfile.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also capture stderr to a separate file:

```
sudo python appname.py >> logfile.log 2>> error.log
```